# Unable to use the object with key value 'templateUrl' in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the below object in component.ts and I am going to iterate this array in the HTML template inside ui-comp-menu.

```
menuObject = [{
        'labels': 'Content1',
        'templateUrl': 'assets/partials/sample.html',
        'childrens': [],
    },
    {
        'labels': 'Content2',
        'templateUrl': 'assets/partials/sample1.html',
    }];
```

and in the html

```
<ui-comp-menu [data]="menuObject" [label]="'labels'" [url]="'routeUrl'" ></ui-comp-menu>
```

But while compiling I got the below error

ERROR in *./src/app/app.component.ts*

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './assets/partials/UserAdministration.html' in
>   'D:\POC_Angular_6\lib-demo\src\appI

If i change the object key 'templateUrl' to some other name like 'templatePath' issue won't come and compiled successfully. But i am not sure about previous angular versions.

Comment: Apparently Angular considers `templateUrl` to be a reserved key name. Could be considered a bug. Is it a problem to use a different key name?

Comment: From API, i am getting that object with key value 'templateUrl'. else i need to take  copy of this object with different key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug from the `angular-cli` package. When you check the [`source code`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/6449a753641340d8fc19a752e1a1ced75f974efa/packages/ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/replace_resources.ts#L69) you can see that they are parsing the entire .ts file and subtracting any object in there. Then they are checking if there is an object with a `templateUrl` or `styleUrls` key in there.

This seems a bit erratic, and could be done more properly. For instance to check if the subtracted object is inside an annotation (`@Component`).

Couple things you can do here:

- Submit a bug report, wait for them to fix it, and in the meantime replace the key with something else
- Make your own pull request, wait for them to accept it, and etc...
- You say that the data comes from an API, if that's the case, you don't really need to have those hard coded `templateUrl` definitions inside your typescript file. Connecting to the API and removing those from your code should be enough.
- Change the key from the API and just keep it at that